# References for de-amortization

Tags: reference-request, ds.data-structures, lower-bounds, amortized-analysis

I've been interested in looking into the area of de-amortization recently (i.e. finding data structures with matching worst-case and amortized running time bounds, or exhibiting lower bounds against matching the amortized complexity of certain operations with a worst-case bound).

The only reference I've been able to find so far is a [survey](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-68535-9_4) from COCOON by S.R. Kosaraju and M. Pop.

Are there any other good surveys or set of papers to read regarding de-amortization?

Comment: Naor and Yogev [showed a nice de-amortization](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.5872v6.pdf) for their sliding bloom filter structure (section 2.4).

Comment: You can take a look to the recent work of Goodrich, Mitzenmacher et al. on de-amortize oblivious RAM simulations (see also their "previous work" section): [Oblivious RAM simulation with efficient worst-case access overhead](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2046680) and   
[Cache-Oblivious dictionaries and multimaps with negligible failure probability](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2437302)